# Shopware 6 Import Export Event not firing in prod environment

Tags: plugins, shopware, shopware6

i'm subscribing to the following event in a shopware 6 plugin to make some changes when a csv import is occurring:

```php
ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent::class => 'onBeforeImport'
```

then i setup a handler that does some price calculation and sets the price of the product.
But the  event handler onBeforeImport(which sets a price based on imported stuff) only does work when i set the shop to dev environment. if i change to prod it doesn't work anymore and only handles the first row of the imported csv file. i don't understand why that would break the price calculation by setting to prod. there is no error in the import/export module it just doesnt do the product price modification.

```php
public function onBeforeImport(ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent $event):  void
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        if (empty($event->getRecord())) {
            return;
        }

        $wucPluginRangePrice = $event->getRecord()['wucPluginRangePrice'];

            if ($this->IsGram($wucPluginRangePrice['rangeUnit']) && $this->IsKilo($wucPluginRangePrice['priceUnit'])) {

                $criteria = new Criteria();
                $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $event->getRecord()['id']));
                $products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
                $product = null;
                if ($products !== null && !empty($products->getEntities())) {
                    $product = $products->first();
                } else {
                    return;
                }

                $isUseGross = (bool)$this->systemConfigService->get('WucPluginBasepriceWeightRange.config.wucBasepricePricePerUnitGross');
                $toKgValue = ((float)$wucPluginRangePrice['to']) / 1000;
                $taxRateDivident = $product->getTax() !== null ? ($product->getTax()->getTaxRate() / 100) + 1.00 : (19.00 / 100) + 1.00;
                if ($isUseGross) {
                    $priceVal = ((float)$wucPluginRangePrice['pricePerUnit']) * $toKgValue;
                    $netVal = ($priceVal / $taxRateDivident);
                } else {
                    $netVal = ((float)$wucPluginRangePrice['pricePerUnit']) * $toKgValue;
                    $priceVal = ($netVal * $taxRateDivident);
                }
              
                $data = [
                    'id' => $product->getId(),
                    'price' => [
                        [
                            'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,
                            'gross' => $priceVal,
                            'net' => $netVal,
                            'linked' => false
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                $this->productRepository->update([$data], $context);

            }


    }
```

other events work fine for example subscribing to product.written is it a problem with the listening to a ::class when in prod?

Answer (score -1):

`$products->getEntities()` returns an instance of `EntityCollection` and as such `!empty($products->getEntities())` will always yield `true`. `$products->first()` can then be `null` and `$product->getId()` will throw an exception.

Since `ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent` is dispatched within a try/catch block the exception is caught but the import finishes.

Instead of using `empty` prevent further execution with an expression like `$products->getEntities()->count() === 0` or simply check if `$product = $products->first()` yields `null`.

This seems like a likely cause for the behavior. However this should be reproducable in both `prod` and `dev` environments. This depends on your definition of "it works" in either of those environments. Does it throw an exception in one environment where in the other it doesn't? Or does it actually update the prices in one environment and doesn't in the other?

As it stands you will only be able to update products already existing before the import. Is this the desired behavior? Any products that will be initially created by the import will not yet exist when the event is dispatched and as such you can't update prices of a product that's not existing yet. You simply might want to use `ImportExportAfterImportRecordEvent` instead, which will be dispatched after new products have actually been persisted.

For further debugging you should [dump any possible caught exceptions](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/ImportExport.php#L188) caused by your subscription. This will likely provide some more promising leads.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. I applied the solution to handling the entity collection.
Sadly it doesnt change the outcome. The problem persists that everything works fine in dev environment and only the first csv row/product is being updated after switching to prod. Sadly no exception is thrown as well.

It is okay that only updates to existing products are done with this plugin. The updating data will always be based on previously exported products in this case.

Comment: I don't see any way why the same data could only be persisted based on the environment. Such behavior would've been uncovered by automated tests immediately. That is unless of course some 3rd party plugin interferes with logic based on the environment. I would switch to the event dispatched after the product is persisted nonetheless to be sure. If you want your changes to stick, it would only make sense to not take the risk of them getting overwritten immediately. Also check that the imported entity really is a product: `$event->getConfig()['sourceEntity'] === 'product'`

Comment: that is also good advice. i built around some logging and it seems the event that im subscribing to is not firing at all to my handler. i have got some other subscribed events in this `EventSubscriberInterface` and they are working flawlessly. but i don't get the  `ImportExportAfterImportRecordEvent` when im importing csv. seems like a 3rd party plugin issue or is there a known problem?